# How to write ane with C language to let actionscript3.0 to call?

Tags: actionscript-3

Can you give a tutorial or instance.

How to write ane with C language to let actionscript3.0 to call?

Comment: What are you even asking? Give an example of what you are trying to achieve. What's an "ane"?

Comment: An "ane" is an air native extension. It is a library feature to facilitate calling native libraries from the flash vm

Comment: What platform are you writing the C code on? Windows/OSX/iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I think your asking how to let AS3 call a function from a C program. Here is a helpful link:

- [Operating on Actionscript Objects with C/C++](http://blogs.adobe.com/flascc/2012/12/08/operating-on-actionscript-objects-in-c/)

Please note as stated in the blog -

> Question : ...can we use some library like WINUSB in c++ to
>   connect to custom usb device and transfer data to Flash? 
>   Answer : FlasCC compiled content runs inside the Flash Player’s
>   secure sandbox and only has access to the same Flash APIs that a
>   normal Flash application has access to. This means you cannot access
>   USB devices in the way you want as there is no API to do that.

### Update :

I thought that `ane` was a misspelling at the writing of this answer, however I believe that my answer should still work. Let me know if it doesn't and I'll continue trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great tutorial/introduction document that Adobe has put out here:

[AIR Extensions PDF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/extensions/air_extensions.pdf)

It guides you through all the concepts of creating the AS and native libraries and then wrapping them together into an ANE. Great place to start.